# Move mouse to trigger a hover event in CasperJS

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs, mousehover

I can't understand, why `mouse::move()` doesn't work. For example on [this page](http://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/Desert%20Eagle%20%7C%20Conspiracy%20%28Minimal%20Wear%29?filter=sticker).

As you can see, there are 10 elements and after moving mouse cursor at the every picture you will see detailed information. I have a set of every element id. I want to move cursor on every element, then selector "div#hover_item_descriptors" will be updated and I will work with it. It's my code:

```
this.eachThen(ids, function(resp){
  var id = resp.data;

  this.then(function(){
    this.mouse.move('span#' + id + '_name'); //moving at the name of element
  });

  this.waitUntilVisible('div#hover_item_descriptors div#sticker_info', function(){
    // it`s never work, because moving doesn't work
  });
});
```

Why does it not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd stumbled at this too, figured it out thanks to this issue: https://github.com/n1k0/casperjs/issues/208

It turns out if you are hovering cursor over an element that is **not in the viewport**, hover event won't work.

So, to make it work, set viewport height that is guaranteed to exceed page height, for example:

```
var casper = require('casper').create({
    viewportSize : { width: 1280, height: 5000 }
});
```